# Duration.between vs ChronoUnit.between

Tags: java, java-time

Are the both methods equivalent?

**version 1:**

```
var diff = Duration.between(begin, end).toHours();
```

**version 2;**

```
var diff = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(begin, end);
```

Are there any implicit differences? If yes, which one should I prefer?

Comment: Very interesting question :) Reading the javadocs, nothing seems to say there is a difference

Comment: Doesn't the first one return a `Duration` and the second one a `long` (*the amount of time between temporal1Inclusive and temporal2Exclusive in terms of this unit; positive if temporal2Exclusive is later than temporal1Inclusive, negative if earlier*)?

Comment: for the love of God, I hope that there is no difference between the two, _specifically_ about `hours`.

Comment: @Eugene cried laughing with the comment

Comment: @Boug yeah... the question is awesome, imo. But I surely hope the answer is as straight forward as it should : **NO, there isn't**. I have been looking at the documentation and implementation and found no meaningful difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyzed implementation on open JDK 15

**A) Duration.between(begin, end).toHours();**

`Duration.between(begin, end)` first calls

```
long until(Temporal endExclusive, TemporalUnit unit); //called with unit of NANOS or SECONDS if first one fails
```

and then parses the difference to create a `Duration` based on nanos that have been calculated (or seconds if calculation of nanos failed)

```
public static Duration between(Temporal startInclusive, Temporal endExclusive) {
        try {
            return ofNanos(startInclusive.until(endExclusive, NANOS));
        } catch (DateTimeException | ArithmeticException ex) {
            long secs = startInclusive.until(endExclusive, SECONDS);
            long nanos;
            try {
                nanos = endExclusive.getLong(NANO_OF_SECOND) - startInclusive.getLong(NANO_OF_SECOND);
                if (secs > 0 && nanos < 0) {
                    secs++;
                } else if (secs < 0 && nanos > 0) {
                    secs--;
                }
            } catch (DateTimeException ex2) {
                nanos = 0;
            }
            return ofSeconds(secs, nanos);
        }
```

Then you have to call `toHours()` which then parses the created `Duration` object to return the hours as long

**B) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(begin, end);**

Directly calls

```
long until(Temporal endExclusive, TemporalUnit unit);

//But instead of the implementation before, now it is called with unit of HOURS directly
```

which directly returns the hours as long.

**Comparison of implementations**

Both work the same way (for Hours at least) and give the same result.

But for **A** it seems we have some back and forth conversions which are not necessary.

Solution **B** seems straight forward without any conversions that we don't need

**Answer**

I would chose **B** as more efficient

Comment: which part of the question was not clear, though? `Duration.between(begin, end).toHours()` returns a `long`; and `ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(begin, end)` returns a `long`. This is what the OP asked, as such your answer does not answer anything

Comment: @Eugene updated previous answer to bring some insight to the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems that both methods finally call `Temporal#until`

### **var diff = Duration.between(begin, end).toHours();**

```
Duration#between
\
 Temporal#until (used twice but some branching go for another implementation)
```

### **var diff = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(begin, end);**

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS#between
\
 Temporal#until (it is the only method underlying)
```

Comment: That's a bit vague. I looked in the source and it seems that version 1 does a lot of stuff in compare to version 2.